# Event Propagation With One Event Listener And Nested Children

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website, I have some `div` elements with some content. Each of the elements is supposed to be clickable. I could add a separate event listener to each one, but I would rather have a single event listener attached to the container. To better explain the document structure, I have added an example below.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Element 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Element 2</h1>
    <p>...dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is the following: I know that using `event.target` gets me the actual element that has been clicked, which - when using one event listener that is attached to the `div` with the ID `container` - could be the container, one of the direct children, or the text elements inside them. How can I determine which of the inner `div` elements - if any - the user clicked, even if the target is not the `div` itself?

If there is a different/simpler solution using JQuery, I would also be interested in that.

Comment: Given that you know that `event.target` gives you a reference to the element which was clicked... this seems to answer your question already? This is the 'jQuery' way of doing it too. Note that there is also the `event.currentTarget` property which, in a delegated event handler, will always be the parent element which the event was assigned to, not the element which raised the event.

Comment: Give a recognizable class to the common ancestor (the _inner div elements_") divs, then check that `event.target.closest('.recognizable-class')` exists. If it does, it's also the div you want to get.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there a simpler way than testing wether the target is a `div` and using the parent element if it is not?
The information about `event.currentTarget` helps a lot.

Comment: @Teemu Couldn't I just use the `closest()` function to get the next `div` element and then check if it has the container ID or not? Either way, you helped me a lot as well.

Comment: That depends on the actual markup. In your case it probably would work, you'll need that additional check, though.

Comment: @Ralph You could also attach the event like `$('#container').on('click', '#container > div', handler);`. Then the event will fire only inside the direct child divs of `#container'`, including a child, but not outside of the child divs. In this case, `this` will refer to the inner div you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the contents of each div (p and h1) to have interactive elements (such as form items), then you can add an extra div wrapper that is unclickable :). Now all your click targets will be the first child divs.

```js
document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("click", (e) => console.log(e.target))
```

```css
.unclickable {
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
          <div>
             <div class="unclickable">
               <h1>Element 1</h1>
               <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div>
             <div class="unclickable">
               <h1>Element 2</h1>
               <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
             </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments under the question your goal is to find an effective way to determine if the user clicked on the outer `div` or one of the child elements.

To do that you compare the `target` property of the event, which is the element that raised the event, to the `currentTarget` property, which will always be the element the event was bound to. The logic would look something like this:

```js
$('#container').on('click', e => {
  if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {
    console.log('clicked on parent');
  } else {
    console.log(`clicked on child element - ${e.target.tagName}`);
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Element 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Element 2</h1>
    <p>...dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the CSS in the above example is just to make the bounds of each element more visible.